# Angular router loads component before redirecting?

Tags: angular, redirect, routes

I'm creating an Angular app that should consist of only 4 routes:
'/one', '/two', '/three', '/four'.
Any other path should be redirected to '/one' - Including ' '.

My AppComponent template looks like this:

```
// Some HTML
...
<some-component>
...
// More HTML
...
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
```

The router-outlet is, of course, where the component associated with the current path ('/one', '/two', '/three' or '/four') should be rendered.

I tried applying the redirection by adding a 'redirectTo' in my routing module as such:

```
  { path: 'one', component: OneComponent},
  { path: 'two', component: TwoComponent},
  { path: 'three', component: ThreeComponent},
  { path: 'four', component: FourComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/one'}
```

When I try loading the ' ' URL, it does in fact get redirected to '/one' and everything in the OneComponent is rendered as expected, but everything in the AppComponent isn't. The browser log shows an error.

I then tried to redirect using a canActive guard, and got the same result.

My problem seems to be that 'some-component' has some logic which fails given an invalid route. I can fix this, but I thought it would be easier to simply redirect before an invalid path gets requested. It seems that redirecting doesn't bypass that problem.

I know I haven't supplied any real code to look into, but my question is this:
Is it possible that given an invalid route AppComponent is being rendered (or attempted to) before the router redirects?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's help.
My question was more theoretical. As I thought of it more, it makes sense that AppComponent is loaded regardless if the route is valid or not, because routing and redirecting only affects any component that should be rendered in the 'router-outlet'.

So I'll just have to fix my logic in the 'some-component'.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to recreate your problem, but I failed. but what I guess, you forgot to add pathMatch: 'full'

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/one', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the error?

As far as I know every time I get this kind of error it will be in the final component in your case `onecomponent` try reloading the page after it finish routing is everything is OK or there still be error?